# Add new Case Comment through Email

Tags: email2case, servicecloud, service, case-comment

Is it possible to add email response as new case comment? When an internal user comment on the case the customer receives an email. I want that When the customer replies to that case comment email, a new case comment record on the same case gets created.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the Email to Case feature. Salesforce has good [instructions on setting up Email to Case](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customizesupport_email.htm&type=5), so I'm not going to repeat them here.

The basic gist of it is that your agents will be sending emails from support@yourcompany.com which should be configured to point to your specific email to case email address in Salesforce. If the email contains a refid in the subject or body, Salesforce will attach it to the case. If not, a new case is created.